# is_file() returns false in Zend Framework 2 model

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm learning Zend Framework 2 and I'm trying to connect to ldap using the info here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.ldap.html.

This line is returning false: $configReader->fromFile('foo.ini')

Looking into the source Zend\Config\Reader\Ini is_file() is returning false.  I've chmoded the entire entire app to 777 just so permissions are not an issue.

I set up a test which you can see here:

```
app/public/ldapconfig.ini
app/public/isfiletest.php
--- var_dump(is_file('ldapconfig.ini')); (true)

app/module/Foo/src/Foo/Model/ldapconfig.ini
app/module/Foo/src/Foo/Model/Bar.php
--- var_dump(is_file('ldapconfig.ini')); (false)
```

The last line of the code above is in a public function that is being called by the controller.
Any ideas why there is a difference in behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how Zend framework is set up but I think when you exec the code the root path is different

try

```
var_dump(is_file('../module/Foo/src/Foo/Model/ldapconfig.ini'));
```

or

```
var_dump(is_file('./ldapconfig.ini'));
```

Comment: var_dump(is_file('../module/Foo/src/Foo/Model/ldapconfig.ini')); (false)

Comment: var_dump(is_file('./ldapconfig.ini')); (false)

Comment: var_dump(is_file('module/Foo/src/Foo/Model/ldapconfig.ini')); (true) - I don't know why though.

Answer (score 1):

For clarification to Ards answer:

Everything within ZF2 is based off of the Projects ROOT Path. This is done at public/index.php  using `chdir(dirname(__DIR__));`. This means that every future include is based off of the projects `./`

Furthermore i suggest following best practices and place the config file into the config folder `./module/Foo/config/ldapconfig.ini`. This makes much more sense than placing a configuration file into the models sources ;)

One last note: INI-parsing (as done in ZF1) is much less slower than is ZF2-Style (or rather basic PHP) Arrays ;) You might want to switch back to the basics, too.